# JRuby: closing runScriptlet if it takes too long?

Tags: java, ruby, multithreading, jruby, thread-sleep

I want to use JRuby to run Ruby scripts.

However, I'd like it so that if a script takes longer than `t` seconds, it will automatically be closed.

Here's my attempt:

```java
ScriptingContainer ruby = new ScriptingContainer();
int t = 3;

new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(t * 1000); // Timeout
                        System.out.println("Timeout passed.");
                        ruby.terminate(); // This has no effect?
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();

Object output = ruby.runScriptlet(scriptWithAnInfiniteLoop);
ruby.terminate(); // Terminate without timeout, at the end of the script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer using the **deprecated** `Thread.stop()`:

```java
        ScriptingContainer ruby = new ScriptingContainer();
        int t = 5;

        String script = content;
        Thread runner = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ruby.runScriptlet(script);
                    ruby.terminate(); // Close normally.
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ruby.terminate(); // Close if JRuby crashes.
                }
            }
        };

        Thread killer = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(t * 1000);
                    runner.stop();
                    ruby.terminate(); // Close forcefully.
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        };

        runner.start();
        killer.start();
```

See this article on why it is deprecated: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Since I am using a deprecated method I won't mark this as an official answer.